# Split a string but consider 1 separator in all splits

Tags: excel, vba

I have an `output_file` which looks like `0001_1234_abcd_defg_U_2018.08.24-14.50.23.TIF`

I am trying to split this file value and paste the splitted values into a table in column C:H starting the immediate available row.

I am using the below code to achieve this.

```
 tbl.Range(LastRow, "C").Offset(1).Value = Split(output_file, "_")(0)
 tbl.Range(LastRow, "D").Offset(1).Value = Split(output_file, "_")(1)
 tbl.Range(LastRow, "E").Offset(1).Value = Split(output_file, "_")(2)
 tbl.Range(LastRow, "F").Offset(1).Value = Split(output_file, "_")(3)
 tbl.Range(LastRow, "G").Offset(1).Value = Split(output_file, "_")(4)
 tbl.Range(LastRow, "H").Offset(1).Value = Split(output_file, "_")(5)
```

But sometimes my `output_file` has 2 underscores in a feild eg `0001_1234__abcd_defg_U_2018.08.24-14.50.23.TIF`. The above code fails in such cases. How to I handle this scenario.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Should it split once on a double-underscore, or zero times? Do you want to just replace the doubles with a single? (ie., [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/replace-function)) If you need to retain the double's, replace them with a temp character, like`|`, then do your split, then replace again to switch back to what you need.

Comment: i meant the code should be able to identify and treat the double underscores as 1 , no matter wherever the double underscore is. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
Sub test()

Dim a() As String

a = Split(replace("123_456_789","__","_"), "_")

Range("h1").Resize(1, UBound(a) + 1).Value = a

End Sub
```

Comment: Personally I think this is a better solution. Although they are effectively the same the use of `UBound` will allow the range to auto resize instead of having the static value and risking cutting off values

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
tbl.Range(LastRow, "C").resize(1, 6).Offset(1, 0) = _
  split(replace(output_file, "__", "_"), "_")
```